# <gazebo_ros> tag in ROS plugin un-supported

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I follow the ROS plugin [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_plugins&cat=connect_ros). And when I catkin_make, the error outputs is:

> Invalid package manifest
> "/home/winston/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_plugin/package.xml":
> Error(s) in
> /home/winston/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_plugin/package.xml:
>
> - The manifest (with format version 1) must not contain the following tags:
>   gazebo_ros

So the problem is the `<gazebo_ros>` tag in the package.xml file. This is my package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>gazebo_ros_plugin</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The gazebo_ros_plugin package</description>
  <maintainer email="winston@todo.todo">winston</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>gazebo_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>

  <gazebo_ros plugin_path="${prefix}/lib" gazebo_media_path="${prefix}" />

  <export>
   </export>
</package>
```

However, if I put the `<gazebo_ros>` tag inside `<export>` tag, this error disappears but new errors occur:

> In file included from /home/winston/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_plugin/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:1:0:
> /usr/include/gazebo-5.0/gazebo/common/Plugin.hh:367:3:
> error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
> }
> ^
> /home/winston/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_plugin/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:26:1:
> note: in expansion of macro
> ‘GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN’
> GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(WorldPluginTutorial)
> ^

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8218/%3Cgazebo_ros%3E-tag-in-ros-plugin-un-supported/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ratnesh Madaan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/662/ratnesh-madaan/) on 2015-03-12**:
class VisualPlugin : public PluginT
{
public: VisualPlugin()
{this->type = VISUAL_PLUGIN;}   (This is lined 367 in Plugin.hh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have found out the answer to my question. Hope it  is useful to anyone else.

1. It is correct to put `<gazebo_ros>` inside `<export>` tag. That is :

FYI,  there is another relevant [answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6416/using_a_urdf_in_gazebo-package-uris-not-described/?answer=6419#post-id-6419).

2. The build error occurs because I have left out a bracket "}" at the end of my source file.

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2015-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1